# How to smoothly move the current position in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, move, marker, smoothing

In my Android project I need that when the vehicle is moving, the marker position should also move smoothly, but when location is changed, the marker is jumping from one position to another, it is not moving smoothly.

I searched a lot, but did not get the result.
I do not know what the best way is. Please give me full guidance.

thank you very much

**Update**

@AnkitMehta thank you for answer

all code in MapsActivity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

  private GoogleMap mMap;
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
  LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
  GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  Location mLastLocation;
  Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop Location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
      LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
  }


  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
      // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
      // in a raw resource file.
      boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
        MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
          this, R.raw.style_json));

      if (!success) {
        Log.e("LOG" , "Style parsing failed.");
      }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
      Log.e("LOG", "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }

    //initialize Google play Services
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Location Permission already granted
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

      } else {
        // Request Location Permission
        checkLocationPermission();
      }
    } else {
      buildGoogleApiClient();
      mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


  }

  protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
      .addApi(LocationServices.API)
      .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
  }


  @Override
  public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    //mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
    //mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
      mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    animateMarker(latLng, latLng, true);


    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
  }

  public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
  private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
      != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

      // Should we show an explanation?
      if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
          .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
          .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
          .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
              //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
          })
          .create()
          .show();


      } else {
        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
          new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
          MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
          && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

          // permission was granted, yay! Do the
          // location-related task you need to do.
          if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
              buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
          }

        } else {

          // permission denied, boo! Disable the
          // functionality that depends on this permission.
          Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return;
      }

      // other 'case' lines to check for other
      // permissions this app might request
    }
  }


  //This methos is used to move the marker of each car smoothly when there are any updates of their position
  public void animateMarker(final LatLng startPosition, final LatLng toPosition,
                            final boolean hideMarker) {


    final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
      .position(startPosition)
      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    final long duration = 1000;
    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
        float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
          / duration);
        double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
          * startPosition.longitude;
        double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
          * startPosition.latitude;

        marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

        if (t < 1.0) {
          // Post again 16ms later.
          handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
        } else {
          if (hideMarker) {
            marker.setVisible(false);
          } else {
            marker.setVisible(true);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the code(for moving camera on map) you have written so far?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(latLng)
                                .build();
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
map.animateCamera(cu);
```

> this will move to the latlng selected with animation(Camera position
>   and camera update is used)

Comment: //move map camera
    instead of :
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));

only do:
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));

you need to use only animateCamera and not moveCamera

Comment: Thank you very much,

Your code Improved my code 

But when I'm in my car my location on the map does not show up fluently, but after a few seconds it will jump to another location...

What is the reason?

Comment: May be u are not using low latency for updates... It saves battery but takes longer time to provide updatedlocation

Comment: OK

 But In App Google Maps, this is a smooth move

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mlocationListener); mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient); if(mLastLocation!=null){ Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES! mLastLocation!=null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude(); double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude(); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude = " + latitude + "\nLongitude = " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
Declare distance(m) n time (ms)

Comment: Refresh time can be 1000ms n distance u can set 5m for quicker updates or just check by changing. Lower values will provide low latency but cobsume more power

Comment: I have a mLocationRequest in onConnected
Would you replace it with my code?

Comment: i put this code in onConnected method and comment my code but crash app in start

Comment: Hii, sorry for the late reply. I dnt have my laptop vd me right now. Tommorow will edit n update in ur code

Comment: oh not sorry my friend ;

thank you very very very much :)

Comment: If you don't want the zoom to change, you can add `.zoom(map.getCameraPosition().zoom)` to the `CameraPosition.Builder`.

Answer (score 1):

Override this method :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChange(Location location) {
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
     refreshMapPosition(latLng, 45)
}


private void refreshMapPosition(LatLng pos, float angle) {
    CameraPosition.Builder positionBuilder = new CameraPosition.Builder();
    positionBuilder.target(pos);
    positionBuilder.zoom(15f);
    positionBuilder.bearing(angle);
    positionBuilder.tilt(60);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(positionBuilder.build()));
}
```

This overridden method was implementing on GoogleMap classes and map variable is variable that we define to load google map instance.

Please refer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views