# react-native-maps user location smooth movement

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

My react native project code looks like this:

```
  const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
  
  const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
  const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.003;  
  const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

  const mapView = useRef(null)

  const onLocationChange = async (region) => {

    const pstn = region.nativeEvent.coordinate;

    mapView.current?.animateToRegion(
      {
        latitude: pstn.latitude,
        longitude: pstn.longitude,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      }, 
    1000)
  }
  
  <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
        style={styles.map}
        ref={c => mapView.current = c}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: coordinates.latitude,
          longitude: coordinates.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: coordinates.latitudeDelta,
          longitudeDelta: coordinates.longitudeDelta
        }}
        onUserLocationChange={onLocationChange}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        minZoomLevel={15}   
        maxZoomLevel={20}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={false}
        moveOnMarkerPress={false}
        toolbarEnabled={false}
        rotateEnabled={true}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        mapType={'standard'}
   />
```

I have a question to ask.

[image]

As you can see from the animation above, each time there's a progress, region is centralized, but location pointer jumps straightaway to new coordinate.

My question is, how do I make pointer move smoothly from previous to next coordinate?

Comment: You may get better answers if you split this into two questions - usually one question per post is encouraged

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to smoothly move the current position in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423191/how-to-smoothly-move-the-current-position-in-google-maps)